# Force Firebase dynamic link to open in app browser

Tags: android, firebase, hyperlink, firebase-dynamic-links

If you create a dynamic link using the firebase console, it provides an option to define link behavior to either open the link in app or in a browser. How do we force a link to be opened only in a browser while creating the dynamic link with the REST API? Is there any parameter we can define to force this behavior?

[image]

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest if there is a parameter . I think you can do this way too just do not mention the host or path for this link in manifest which you don't want to open in app .

Comment: enableForcedRedirect doesn't do it. I think there is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try skipping the `apn` parameter from the url while create dynamic link from Rest API.
This will by default open the link in the browser.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am actually trying to use the "Create with parameters" option. Anyway, let me give it a shot. I'll update after.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. happy coding

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force open the website using programmatically created short dynamic link in 4/2020. I tried them all. If the app is installed, it will always open the app and there isn't any param when you create dynamic link programmatically to force open it in the website. Funny because in console when you create it there, you can specify to force open in the website. If I am wrong, please comment or correct me. Filed the bug report to Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5376

Comment: whats does curl -v https://[tld-of-desitnation-link]/.wellknown/apple-app-site-association return, and is your destination's tld included xcode entitlements associated domains applinks:foo.com, if it is included try adding "paths": [ 'NOT /path/to/wwwONLY/*'] to your apple-app-site-association