# HandleCodeInApp false not redirecting to web browser when generating password reset link Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to generate a reset password link with the Firebase Admin SDK in a Cloud Function.

This works great.
However, if i click on the link (inside my mailbox) from a smartphone, it opens back my application and not my website.

I was hoping than setting `handleCodeInApp: false` would open the link in the browser but it doesn't. I have tried to set it to `true` to see if there would be a difference but no unfortunately...

I have not tried with other methods than `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink()` but maybe it will also happen.

Here is my `ActionCodeSettings` object :

```
const codeSettings = {
      url: "https://www.example.com/handler/_resetPassword",
      iOSBundleId: "com.mypackage",
      handleCodeInApp: false,
      androidPackageName: 'com.mypackage'
    }
```

I have done the setup of Firebase Dynamic Links as well.

How can i make the link to open the browser instead of the mobile app ?

**Note** :  I have made an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7074) in the `Flutter` repo as there seem to be many about the whole process. However, my question is not about Flutter, only Cloud function that seems to not be working for this use case.

EDIT :

It seems (according to Firebase Support) that there is no bug in the native SDKs :

> We still have not been able to replicate this issue with the official IOS SDK, I have followed all the steps mentioned here , but no luck.

The [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions) link.

So I will have to make more tests to see why this bool value is not working.
Hopefully in the meantime, someone with a solution will post it here !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Firebase dynamic link to open in app browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870849/force-firebase-dynamic-link-to-open-in-app-browser)

Comment: Unfortunately no, as i am only trying to use the firebase authentication SDK + Cloud Functions. This uses dynamic links implicitely but it's not up to me to handle this. If i don't provide the ```dynamicLinkDomain``` param in ```ActionCodeSettings``` it will use the first by default (from the documentation). Also, i can't "not shorten the url" because again i am not dealing with the dynamic link itself, despite it may work.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Have you tried to create the link manually and email it to the customer?

Comment: Yes i am still facing the issue and it's awaiting an answer from Firebase Support. I will post it here once i have a solution but it seems related to flutter because the native SDK (according to the support so far) is working fine.
Creating the link manually works.

Comment: lol i want it to work like it works for you but instead it always the link in the browser, how do you manage to make it open in the app ?

Comment: haha sorry to hear that ! Unfortunately i have no idea... On Android it always ask me to choose between both actually, which is also not desired. But on IOS i have no choice but to be redirected to the app :)